# Close jQueryUI Dialog from event of ajax loaded content element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I load content with .load() passing url.
Inside of the content that is returned and loaded sucessfully into jq ui dialog, is simple link with id cancel123.
I am just trying to close this jqueryUiDialog w ID testDialog from click on the link.
I cannot figure out what im missing, and tried to do it in 48 different ways. Please help

```
 function InitializeDialog($element, title, url) {

            $element.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 500,
                resizable: true,
                draggable: true,
                title: title,
                model: true,
                show: 'slide',
                closeText: 'x',
                //dialogClass: 'alert',
                closeOnEscape: true,
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    //Load the Partial View Here using Controller and Action
                    $element.load(url);
                    $("#cancel123").bind('click', function (event) {
                        $('#testDialog').dialog('close');
                        alert('close this');
                    });


                },

                close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Is there any error? How does it behaves?

Comment: it just does not close it, no error, does nothing. What i see is happening, is i cannot bind to event of dynamicly loaded element, it's not so jquery ui dialog close issues, as perhaps jquery .load content isssue. in my example there is an alert it does not fire also.

Comment: the only way i can get it to work is add onclick
`code`<a href="#" id="cancel123" class="btn btn-link dialog-cancel" onclick="closeDialog();">Cancel</a> and than executing dialog close from within function `code`
 function closeDialog() {
            $('#testDialog').dialog('close');
        }

Comment: I cant seem to do anything with the event of this a href in jquery ui dialog loaded content, does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind it to the document like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#cancel123", function(event) {
    $('#testDialog').dialog('close');
    alert('close this');
});
```

Another way (I think its even better):

```
$element.load(url, function() {
    $("#cancel123").bind('click', function (event) {
        $('#testDialog').dialog('close');
        alert('close this');
    });
});
```

Comment: that still does not work. I think for some reason i cannot bind to events of element that came loaded as part of ajax call into dialog. does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think so.. Is it into an iframe?

Comment: no, its not. $(document).on("click", "#cancel123", function(event) {... does work, but not 2nd method.
does this mean its gonna listen to all clicks and see if the id of element being clicked on is cancel123, would that perform ok?

Comment: Yes, it means that. Generally it doesn't generate perf troubles, but if you've got a really big DOM, it might be a problem.